# Help: induction exercise $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left ( \frac{1}{i^{2}} +i\right )\leq \frac{n^{3}+n^{2}+4n-2}{2n}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation, induction

I' m doing this induction exercise:
$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left ( \frac{1}{i^{2}} +i\right )\leq \frac{n^{3}+n^{2}+4n-2}{2n}$ where $n\geq 1$

I ve proved step p(1) , now i m doing the induction step. I ve done few calculation for n+1: $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left ( \frac{1}{i^{2}} +i\right )\leq \frac{n^{4}+3n^{3}+7n^{2}+7n}{2(n+1)^2}$

At this point i need help. I think yo subtract $ \frac{n^{3}+n^{2}+4n-2}{2n}$ to show the result is greater than 0

Comment: Since $\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac12n(n+1)$, I guess one of the $n^3$ should be replaced by $n^2$.

Comment: First of all this is equivalent to proving $\sum_1^n \frac{1}{i^2} \le 2-\frac 1n$ which is true since $\frac{\pi^2}{6} \lt 2$.

Comment: @AnneBauval yes there was a typo

Comment: I don't understand which "calculations you have done for n+1"

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left ( \frac{1}{i^{2}} +i\right )+1 / (n+1)^2+(n+1) \leq p(n+1)$ and then only calculations

Comment: @Vishu The simplification is fine, but just because in the limit the inequality holds doesn't mean it should hold for finite $n$.

Comment: @Macavity Check enough $n$ until $2-\frac 1n \gt \frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are allowed to use $\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{n(n+1)}2$ then, by Vishu's comment, the proposed duplicate will do.

If you are not then, after your (correct) calculations, there remains to check that
$$\frac{n^{3}+n^{2}+4n-2}{2n}\le\frac{n^{4}+3n^{3}+7n^{2}+7n}{2(n+1)^2},$$
i.e.
$$(n^{3}+n^{2}+4n-2)(n^2+2n+1)\le n(n^{4}+3n^{3}+7n^{2}+7n)$$
i.e.
$$n^5+3n^4+7n^3+7n^2-2\le n^5+3n^4+7n^3+7n^2
$$
i.e.
$$-2\le0,$$
which is true.

Comment: He did not claim he proved $A(n)\le\frac{n^{4}+3n^{3}+7n^{2}+7n}{2(n+1)^2}.$ He only computed $p(n+1)-\frac1{(n+1)^2}-(n+1)=\frac{n^{4}+3n^{3}+7n^{2}+7n}{2(n+1)^2},$ and concluded that in order to prove the induction step $A(n)\le p(n)\Rightarrow A(n+1)\le p(n+1)$, he only needed to prove that $p(n)\le \frac{n^{4}+3n^{3}+7n^{2}+7n}{2(n+1)^2},$ which I did.

Answer (score 1):

From Vishu's comment, it suffices to show that

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n{1\over i^2}\le2-\frac1n
$$

This is trivial when $n=1$. Assume the inequality holds for $n$, so we have

\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}{1\over i^2}
&\le2-\frac1n+{1\over(n+1)^2}=2-{(n+1)^2-n\over n(n+1)^2} \\
&=2-{n^2+n+1\over n(n+1)^2}<2-{n^2+n\over n(n+1)(n+1)}=2-{1\over n+1}
\end{aligned}

Thus, the induction step is complete.

Comment: Or $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} < \frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}.$ *Everyone's a critic*.

Comment: @user2661923 Your approach is indeed simpler than mine.